# Rubocop Lint/Void: Literal used in void context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I have been running rubocop and encountered a *Lint/Void: Literal used in void context* offence.

the following code:

```
routes_and_postcodes.each do |hash|
  2..7.each do |i|
    route = Route.where(name: hash[:route]).first if postcode.delete(" ").first(i) == hash[:postcode].delete(" ")
  end
end
```

I have read the [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Lint/Void), but still cant understand what the issue is.
In context, the full code is here:

```
def choose_own_van_route(postcode)
route = nil
routes_and_postcodes = []
Route.all.each do |r|
  route_postcodes = r.postcode_array
  route_postcodes.each do |pc|
    routes_and_postcodes << { postcode: pc, route: r.name }
  end
end
routes_and_postcodes.each do |hash|
  2..7.each do |i|
    route = Route.where(name: hash[:route]).first if postcode.delete(" ").first(i) == hash[:postcode].delete(" ")
  end
end
route || Route.create(cut_off_time_mins_since_midnight: 0, name: "BLANK ROUTE HAD TO BE ASSIGNED")
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
2..7.each do |i|
  # ...
end
```

...is **invalid code**!! Have you tried running it? You'll see the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for 7:Integer
```

To fix this, you need to define the `Range` in brackets:

```
(2..7).each do |i|
  # ...
end
```

The `rubocop` error is in relation to this: Since *if* there were an `each` method defined on `Integer` (there isn't, but `rubocop` doesn't know that), then the code would be valid but the `2..<something>` range definition would serve no purpose; it's a *literal* with a *void context*.

Comment: For me, it turns out that I forgot to enclose my `let` block with an `end`